# Why am I getting different results from diff commands in Sublime Text 2

Tags: diff, sublimetext2

I am reconciling a group of text files, many of which have the exact same content. Using Sublime Text 2, I can diff these files in one of two ways (there may be more, I don't know)

1. Open the two files, *right-click* on one, and select `Diff with Tab....`
2. Without having any tabs open, *right-click* on the file in my folder structure on the sidebar and select `Diff with File in Project...`, from there I select the file to `diff`

For two files that contain the same content, **option 1** flashes a message at the bottom indicating `no difference`. **option 2** however opens a new diff results file, and indicates that the entire contents of file 2 should be replaced with file 1.

---

As an example here is the result of option 2 on some test files

```
    --- C:\path\to\test\file\a\test_b.txt 
    +++ C:\path\to\test\file\b\test_a.txt 
    @@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
    -This
    -is
    -a
    -test
    -file
    -to
    -test
    -diff
    +This
    +is   
    +a    
    +test    
    +file    
    +to    
    +test    
    +diff
```

---

Is this an issue with how I am using diff, i.e. am I misunderstanding what should be returned in a diff output?

What is the difference in **option 1** and **option 2** above in how Sublime Text 2 diff's the two files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be because of the line endings (CR/LF) being altered by adding the file to the project?

Comment: That is exactly what the issue was... Thanks for the suggestion